# Java component positioning on GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to position components on JPanel using GridBagLayout but the output I am getting is completely off from what I expect. Hope to get some clarity with brilliant-minded ppl in stackoverflow:).

Below I have provided a piece of code and screentshot of the program. My questions are:

1. Why the JLabel `Choose measure system to convert` is not on `Y-axis = 1`? As to my knowledge, `c.gridy=1` is one pixel downward, but the label is stuck on the top leaving no space from the Frame title. And also, why is it positioned so weird, i.e., not really in the center, nor in the start?
2. Why is there such a big space between `ComboBox`es `From...` and `To...`, but there is no space between ComboBox `To...` and `TextField` `Enter value here...`?

Here is the code:

```
    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    getContentPane().add(container, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    TitledBorder outputCenter;
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    label = new JLabel("Choose measure system to convert");
    label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    container.add(label, c);

    fromList = new JComboBox<String>(convertFrom); 
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    container.add(fromList, c);

    toList = new JComboBox<String>(convertTo);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    container.add(toList, c);

    //Field where user enters the value to be converted
    input = new JTextField("Enter value here...");
    input.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,30));;
    input.setEditable(true);
    input.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    input.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    input.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            input.setText("");}});
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 2;
    container.add(input, c);
```

And here is the screentshot:

[image: GridBagLayout]

EDIT: If I change the code from:

```
    label = new JLabel("Choose measure system to convert");
    label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    c.gridx = 0; 
    c.gridy = 1;
    container.add(label, c);

    label = new JLabel("Choose measure system to convert");
    label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    c.gridx = 1; // changed this line
    c.gridy = 1;
    container.add(label, c);
```

The outcome is like this: 
[image]

This is very confusing me as why changing the position of one component effects everything?

Comment: `This is very confusing me as why changing the position of one component effects everything?` - you moved the label from the first column to the second column. The width of each column is determined by the width of the largest component added to the column. So as you move the label from the first to second column the width of columns change taking into account each component added to each column.

Comment: In the first example the label is the largest component is the first column and the  "from" combo box is centered within the column. In the second example again the label is the largest in the second column and the "to" combo box is centered in the column. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout]() for more information and explanation of all the constraints and for working examples.

Comment: @camickr, thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GridBagConstraints sets up the frame into effectively a grid. The width and height of the cells in the grid are determined by the size of the data in the cell by default unless otherwise specified. So if you want to add some space in-between cells I suggest `ipadx` and `ipady`. You can also utilize `anchor` for adjusting your data in the cell. I also suggest `weightx` and `weighty` for adjusting the actual cell size.

So imagine something like this as your current set up:

[image]

EDIT: Example of what your new GBC looks like. The numbers are (gridx,gridy)

[image]

Comment: I have added an edition. Please can you advise. Why if I change the position of the JLabel it effects the position of all other components? Thanks

Comment: You have to change the position each time for each label because `GridBagConstraints c` is one object that stays the same after each variable is set.

Comment: thanks. How do you mean to change position each time? I am changing it, ie y = 1, y = 2 etc...Or do you mean I have to declare a new GridBagConstraints on every component?

Comment: Whoops have my x and y coordinates flipped. No, you don't have to declare a new GBC (GridBagConstraints) every time. Just reassign the specific values for each item. Play around with the GBC fields until you find something that suits your needs for each item. Like you did with `c.gridx` and `c.gridy`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why the `JLabel` Choose measure system to convert is not on `Y-axis = 1`? As to my knowledge, `c.gridy=1` is one pixel downward

You're confusing yourself, `c.gridy = 1` is not positioning it 1 pixel downward but rather on the next row, but as there's no previous row, then it takes the first row. For reference see: [`GridBagConstraints#gridy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#gridy) which says the following:

> Specifies the cell at the top of the component's display area, where the topmost cell has gridy=0. The value RELATIVE specifies that the component be placed just below the component that was added to the container just before this component was added.

Next question:

> And also, why is it positioned so weird, i.e., not really in the center, nor in the start?

It is centered in its own cell, if you want to center it on the `JFrame`, then you might need to create it on its own `gridx = 1` and the rest of components on the other ones (0 and 2) or make it span 2 or more columns based on you want it to look like...

> Why is there such a big space between ComboBoxes From... and To..., but there is no space between ComboBox To... and TextField Enter value here...?

It is because your program is giving it all the extra space because of the large text on the first cell...

You can have something like this:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridBagLayoutExample {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel pane;
    private JLabel label;
    private JTextField field;
    private JComboBox<String> box1;
    private JComboBox<String> box2;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GridBagLayoutExample()::createAndShowGui);
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());

        pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        label = new JLabel("Choose measure system to convert");

        box1 = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"From..."});
        box2 = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"To..."});

        field = new JTextField(10);

        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5); //We add extra space at top, left, bottom, right of each component

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3; //We make our text to span 3 cells
        pane.add(label, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1; //We return the spanning to 1 single cell
        pane.add(box1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        pane.add(box2, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        pane.add(field, gbc);

        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: @sumu00 if this answer was helpful and answered your question don't forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)